# How to return string as a response to http request

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, maven

In my Maven app I have mapped put http request onto this function(using spring framework), and I want to check something inside it and send response as text. Then I want to send that request from angularjs and store that response into some variable from angularjs controller. This is what I have tried.

```
@RequestMapping(path="/play", method={RequestMethod.POST}, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
public String someFunction(){
    //...
    return "some text";
    }

$scope.getResponse = function(param1, param2...){

            $http.post("url..").then(
                    function(response){
                        $scope.response = response.data.response;
                        console.info('success');
                    },
                    function(response){
                        console.info('failure');
                    })

        }
```

Http is mapped correctly and works from browser, problem is how to store textual response into some angularjs variable from controller.

Comment: @progyammer Yeah, my bad, that function is returning string, edited.

Comment: From next time, don't type code in questions: it's typo prone. Just copy-paste them.

Comment: You should add `@ResponseBody` to spring method

Comment: **`response.data.response`** -- Do you have a key `response` in the response from server?

Comment: @Pete @Hadi I added `@responseBody` and it still won't work. And `response.data` doesn't seem to be a problem as function goes to failure even when i delete whole line `$scope.response = response.data.response`.

Comment: It means your API returns non 2xx status. Can you please check the browsers console or network tab for he XHR from angular?

Comment: **Http is mapped correctly and works from browser** -- how did you test a post request from browser?

Comment: @Pete  I get status 200, so that is fine. Actually I even get response I want (which i found in XHR), but cant copy it into js variable. I tested post request when I click a button and call js function which make request.

Comment: Can you share the result of `console.log(response);` within the success callback? Also are you triggering this http request from the angularjs controller?

Comment: @Pete Well, It never goes on success, it always fail. But when I call `console.log(response)` in failure callback it prints `undefined`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145277/discussion-between-pete-and-wdc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `$http` finds it difficult to parse the invalid JSON data in the response.
We have `produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE}` in there for the API and sending out plain text. That's why it goes to the failure handler.

Change the media type  to `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE` and see if it works...